# C# Syncing HashSet withing Action

Tags: c#

I have a question I have a simple subscriber and simple publisher they look like:

```
public async Task SendRequest()
{
    var topic = "SomeTopic";
    var requestHash = Helpers.ReturnUniqueKey(DateTime.Now, topic);
    requestKeys.Add(requestHash);

    Console.WriteLine($"Key count {requestKeys.Count}");
    var responseHandler = new Action<ResponseMessage>(response =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Key count {requestKeys.Count}");
        foreach (var key in requestKeys)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Response { BitConverter.ToString(response.IdentyficationHash) } - Key { BitConverter.ToString(key) }");
            if (!key.SequenceEqual(response.IdentyficationHash)) return;
            requestKeys.Remove(key);
        }
    });
    bus.Subscribe(BusController.ManualRequest, responseHandler, configuration => configuration.WithTopic(BusController.ManualRequest));

    bus.Publish(someRequest, topic);

    async Task WaitForItToWorkAsync()
    {
        var retry = 0;
        var complete = false;
        while (!complete)
        {
            if (retry >= 20) return ; // Ill ass some msg leater
            complete = !requestKeys.Contains(requestHash);
            retry += 1;
            await Task.Delay(1000);
         }
         return // Ill ass some msg leater
      }  
      await WaitForItToWorkAsync()
}
```

Main idea is I am sending message to some service with some request and wait for arrival (I know i can use rpc, but there can be  any services and rpc dos not support topic), well this path works, problem is that requestKeys HashSet it a field in a class

```
private readonly HashSet<byte[]> requestKeys;
```

As you see on each method invocation I add Key to that field, if I'll make first request it works fine, but other will not update this key collection, I mean outside Action it is updated, but outside it is a problem. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Are you asking on how to make your code thread-safe or what is your actual question and issue?

Comment: I think so, I want to know when response will arrive and add response hash to HashSet so WaitForItToWorkAsync will know that task is completed.

Comment: The response arrives when the `responseHandler` is invoked, isn't it? Or what is `responseHandler`?

Comment: other way around when response arrive from message bus handler is invoked

Comment: So you basically want to block and prevent `SendRequest()` from completing until `responseHandler` has been executed, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to prevent `SendRequest()` from completing until you have received a response, you could use a `SemaphoreSlim` instead of adding and removing keys from a `HashSet`, e.g.:

```
public async Task SendRequest()
{
    var topic = "SomeTopic";

    SemaphoreSlim semaphoreSlim = new SemaphoreSlim(0, 1);
    var responseHandler = new Action<ResponseMessage>(response =>
    {
        //signal that the response has arrived
        semaphoreSlim.Release();
    });
    bus.Subscribe(BusController.ManualRequest, responseHandler, configuration => configuration.WithTopic(BusController.ManualRequest));
    bus.Publish(someRequest, topic);

    //wait for the response to arrive
    await semaphoreSlim.WaitAsync();
    semaphoreSlim.Dispose();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, was fighting with this whole day.